# Is there any point in keeping expired international driving licenses?

Tags: paperwork, international-travel, driving, driving-licenses

Is there any point in keeping expired international driving licenses?

Comment: I guess I never saw a point (but that doesn't mean there isn't one!) It would get flushed from my travel documents when I was next going somewhere and noticed it was expired. No bad outcomes yet (fingers crossed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, since the International Driving Permit (IDP) has expired it cannot be used.

For a new IDP you would need your original driver's licence, so here too it would serve no purpose.